# Error in installing WTP plugin to ADT eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, web-services, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-wtp

I am trying to install WTP plugins but getting error while installing.Can somebody please have a look on it,not able to find its solution

```
Your original request has been modified.
"Eclipse XML Editors and Tools" is already present because other installed software      
requires it.  It will be added to the installed software list.
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
Software being installed: Eclipse Java Web Developer Tools 3.3.2.v201112072049-    
7F7AFO7C25ToiIbpoiuW12GT78Mciy6W7iwuxaco (org.eclipse.jst.web_ui.feature.feature.group   
3.3.2.v201112072049-7F7AFO7C25ToiIbpoiuW12GT78Mciy6W7iwuxaco)
Missing requirement: Structured Source JSP Model 1.2.402.v201112071853   
(org.eclipse.jst.jsp.core 1.2.402.v201112071853) requires 'package 
javax.servlet.jsp.tagext [2.0.0,2.2.0)' but it could not be found
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Eclipse Java Web Development Core 3.3.2.v201112072049-  
7Q7DGLAFE9LeAHGQwz0Yz0Nmuitz01z01sRxi387 (org.eclipse.jst.web_core.feature.feature.group   
3.3.2.v201112072049-7Q7DGLAFE9LeAHGQwz0Yz0Nmuitz01z01sRxi387)
To: org.eclipse.jst.jsp.core [1.2.402.v201112071853]
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Eclipse Java Web Developer Tools 3.3.2.v201112072049-  
7F7AFO7C25ToiIbpoiuW12GT78Mciy6W7iwuxaco (org.eclipse.jst.web_ui.feature.feature.group  
3.3.2.v201112072049-7F7AFO7C25ToiIbpoiuW12GT78Mciy6W7iwuxaco)
To: org.eclipse.jst.web_core.feature.feature.group [3.3.2.v201112072049-
7Q7DGLAFE9LeAHGQwz0Yz0Nmuitz01z01sRxi387]
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error message trying to install the wtp plugin via "Help"->"Install new Software..." in Eclipse Juno.

I found my solution in this post: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/506033/

It stated that I had to make sure the Eclipse Galileo update site (http://download.eclipse.org/releases/galileo/) was available. After I added the update site the installation worked fine. It looks like the Galileo update site includes the package that Eclipse is looking for to resolve the dependencies.

I hope this helps.